# when i compile this code some error has ocures here 1)expression must be a modifiable lvalue 2)identifier "__synchthreads" is undefined

Tags: cuda

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

#define min(x,y) (x>y?x:y)
#define N 33*1024

#define ThreadPerBlock 256

//smallest multiple of threadsPerBlock that is greater than or equal to N
#define blockPerGrid min(32 , (N+ThreadPerBlock-1) / ThreadPerBlock )

__global__ void Vector_Dot_Product ( const float *V1 , const float *V2 , float *V3   )
{
 __shared__ float chache[ThreadPerBlock] ;

float temp ;

 const unsigned int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x ;

 const unsigned int chacheindex = threadIdx.x ;

 while ( tid < N )
{
  temp += V1[tid] * V2[tid] ;

  tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x ;
 }

  chache[chacheindex] = temp ;

 __synchthreads () ;

 int i  = blockDim.x / 2 ;

while ( i!=0 )
 {

  if ( chacheindex < i )
     chache[chacheindex] += chache [chacheindex + i] ;

 __synchthreads () ;

   i/=2 ;
 }

  if ( chacheindex == 0 )
     V3[blockIdx.x] = chache [0] ;


 }

 int main ( int argv , char *argc )
 {
  float *V1_H , *V2_H , *V3_H ;
  float *V1_D , *V2_D , *V3_D ;

  V1_H = new float [N]  ;
  V2_H = new float [N]  ;
  V3_H = new float [blockPerGrid]  ;

  cudaMalloc ( (void **)&V1_D , N*sizeof(float)) ;

  cudaMalloc ( (void **)&V2_D , N*sizeof(float)) ;

  cudaMalloc ( (void **)&V3_D , blockPerGrid*sizeof(float)) ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++ )
  {

          V1_H[i] = i ;

          V2_H[i] = i*2 ;
   } 

   cudaMemcpy ( V1_D , V1_H , N*sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) ;

   cudaMemcpy ( V2_D , V2_H , N*sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) ;

   Vector_Dot_Product <<<blockPerGrid , ThreadPerBlock >>> (V1_D , V2_D , V3_D ) ;

    cudaMemcpy ( V3_H , V3_D , N*sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) ;

    cout <<"\n Vector Dot Prodcut is : " ;

    float sum = 0 ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i<blockPerGrid ; i++ )
           sum+=V3_H[i] ;
    cout << sum << endl ;

    cudaFree ( V1_D) ;
    cudaFree ( V2_D) ;
    cudaFree ( V3_D) ;

       delete [] V1_H ;
       delete [] V2_H ;
       delete [] V3_H ;

    }
```

please tell me what is the problem in this coding......i cant understand ....thanks in advance..

Comment: syncthreads has one h not 2

Comment: You've defined tid as const so you can't modify it in the kernel (tid += ...)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding this:

> identifier “__synchthreads” is undefined

Wherever you have this:

```
__synchthreads();
```

You should change it to this:

```
__syncthreads();
```

Regarding this:

> expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Since you have defined `tid` as `const` here:

```
const unsigned int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x ;
```

You are not allowed to try and change it here:

```
tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x ;
```

So the simplest solution might be to just drop the `const` from the `tid` definition:

```
unsigned int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x ;
```